# How to change a div background colour and keep it highlighed once the new page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, html, onclick

Hope you can help me..Im trying to keep highlighed the div on the top menu in which im currently on, sama as on this website "questions, tags users.."

Here is my site: http://www.ehivemarketing.com/web-design.php

so basicaly the top menu is an include in which is just that:

```
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="web-design.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_webdesign.png"  border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="online-marketing.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_online_marketing.png" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="social-media.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_social_media.png"  border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="#" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_learningcentre.png" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu1"><a href="../index.html" >Home</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../about-ehive-digital.php" >About Us</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../contact-us.php" >Contact Us</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu">Clients</div>
```

this is my CSS for the Hover:

```
.each_text_menu1:hover
{
background-color:#aad400;
}
.each_text_menu:hover
{
background-color:#aad400;
}
```

in which works fine but I need to keep the color background once it is clicked.

Any thoughts of how I could inplement this?

Comment: first of all , nice designing man , secondly u should try  some JQueryUi tool , will be a lot more easier
http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks Mate,
Glad you like it..Just trying to make it look smoothly :)

Its hard for me once Im a designer not a developer..:(

Answer (score 1):

These links may be helpful to you on your work:
 [**link1**](http://www.richnetapps.com/automatically_highlight_current_page_in/) 
and
[**link2**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Dynamic_Menu_Highlighting)

Hope these help you on your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class, let's say `active`, that is the same as `:hover` like this:

```css
.each_text_menu:hover, .each_text_menu.active {
    background-color:#aad400;
}
```

And than check with PHP - as you're using PHP - which page is select and add the active class to this link in the navigation. Could look like this:

```html
<div class="each_text_menu<php print ( 'career' == $page ? ' active' : '' ); ?>">
    <a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for you Reply,
But it doesnt seem to work.. or i might be missing something, I'm not a developer myself I might be missing something crucial here

that's how it looks now:
http://www.ehivemarketing.com/careers.php

Comment: @FabioLucindo Actually it works already, but you've changed the class from `each_text_menu` to `each_circle_menu`. When you change this back and add `active` so that it looks like `each_text_menu active` it works fine - just checked on your site with the browsers development tools.

Comment: Thank mate, but it doesnt seem to work.. you can check it on the link above.. i've replaced the css :


look
<div class="each_text_menu <?php print ( 'career' == $page ? 'active' : '' ); ?>"><a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a></div>

And I gave an ID to the Carrers page on the 
<body id="career">

Any idea what I could possibly doing wrong ?

Comment: Basicaly all I need is that when you are on this page:
http://www.ehivemarketing.com/careers.php doesnt matter wheter you clicked via the menu or landed on it the "careers" item should be "active"

Comment: @FabioLucindo So with my solution you don't need to give a class to the body, only to the `<div>`. But the class doesn't show up at the moment. If all your pages are really unique pages - no re-writing or something, you don't need to use this PHP-part. You can simply add the `active` manually on every page to the corresponding menu item.

Comment: I know the problem is that the menu is an include :(

Comment: Is the current page stored in a variable? If not, you can use this `pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME)` to determine where you are, as this will result in **careers** if we stick to our example link from above. And than `( 'career' == pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) ? 'active' : '' );`. Not the most elegant way, but should work.

Comment: Like this ?
 <div class="each_text_menu <?php print ( 'career' == pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) ? 'active' : '' ); ?>">

Comment: Thanks so much for your patience I'm not a developer.. so its a bit hard somethings for me to understand this:

do I replace the 
__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME  for something? how it would look like if I want it to be my careers page for example..

Thanks and sorry about that..
I cna help with design though :)

Comment: with or without the extension .php ?

Comment: Exactly. And than you gotta do this for every single menu item replacing **career** with the corresponding filename. This is without **.php**.

Comment: the include is sitting inside of a folder /includes and the careers page is on level up on the root.. does it affect ? coz it does not seem to be working :(

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad, if this is within an include use this instead: `pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], PATHINFO_FILENAME)`. Double check what it returns using `print pathinfo($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);`.

Comment: Thanks mate.. I got it working now..:
Appreciatte your help:
www.ehivemarketing.com

Comment: I'm glad I could help. If this fits please approve the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. One simple way to do it is by adding a relevant class to the body tag on each page which you can then reference.

So say your navigation is like this:

```
<ul id="nav">
 <li id="nav1"><a href="#">Nav #1</a></li>
 <li id="nav2"><a href="#">Nav #2</a></li>
 <li id="nav3"><a href="#">Nav #3</a></li>
 <li id="nav4"><a href="#">Nav #4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Your body tag on the homepage would be something like this:

```
<body class="nav1-on">
```

So your css would be:

```
body.nav1-on ul#nav li#nav1 {
 // some css styles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define an additional css class defined like this:

```
.active
{
    background-color:#aad400;
}
```

The on the code that generates the menu, add the class to the corresponding div.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways how to approach this, first is to do the logic in php - check whatever page you're on and echo and add the class to the correct item. Im a bit rusty when it comes to php so there might be errors in the syntax

```
<div class="each_circle_menu <? if($page == 'web-design') { echo "greenBG"; }  ?>">
```

Or you could also use javascript/jquery to do the thing for you

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.each_circle_menu').each(function() {
        var item = $(this);
        if(window.location.indexOf(item.attr('href')) != -1) {
            item.addClass('greenBG');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mate,
Thanks for your reply I've tried your solution but does not seem to work..

This is the item of my menu:
<div class="each_circle_menu <? if($page == 'career') { echo "greenBG"; }  ?>"><a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a></div>

And I gave the body ID="career" on the Careers page..
Am I missing something ?

Thanks

any clue ?

<div class="each_circle_menu <? if($page == 'career') { echo "greenBG"; }  ?>"><a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a></div>

Comment: This was just a quick sample code you were supposed to customize to your needs. $page only represents a variable that has page name in it the check itself doesnt work! In order to make this work, you'll need to change $page to whatever variable can help you decide which page you're on, as well as create the greenBG css class (or whichever name you want)

Answer (score 0):

Use an `.active` class.

```
.each_text_menu1:hover
{
    background-color:#aad400;
}
.each_text_menu:hover
{
    background-color:#aad400;
}
.active{background-color:#aad400;}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="web-design.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_webdesign.png"  border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="online-marketing.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_online_marketing.png" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="social-media.php" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_social_media.png"  border="0"/></a></div>
<div class="each_circle_menu"><a href="#" class="topLink"><img src="images/bt_top_learningcentre.png" border="0" /></a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu1"><a href="../index.html" >Home</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../about-ehive-digital.php" >About Us</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../contact-us.php" >Contact Us</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu"><a href="../careers.php" >Careers</a></div>
<div class="each_text_menu active">Clients</div>
```